# XMLHTTPRequest Byte Range Request

Tags: javascript, json, http, byte

Since I'm downloading a huge JSON file (> 10 MB) via a XHTTPRequest (provided by Google Closure [XhrIo](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio?csw=1)) I want to use Byte Range Requests to download only parts of the data:

```
3.12 Range Units

HTTP/1.1 allows a client to request that only part (a range of) the response entity be included within the response. HTTP/1.1 uses range units in the Range (section 14.35) and Content-Range (section 14.16) header fields. An entity can be broken down into subranges according to various structural units.

  range-unit       = bytes-unit | other-range-unit
  bytes-unit       = "bytes"
  other-range-unit = token

The only range unit defined by HTTP/1.1 is "bytes". HTTP/1.1 implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units.
```

Because the only defined `range-unit` is `bytes` I wonder how to access the requested file char-wise to build up a string. This might be a problem because it is char-code dependent.

**How do I calculate the byte range regarding to the charset of the requested file to access the file char-wise?**

**How can I accumulate the data of the received chunks?**

**How can I create a String or even JSON representation of this requested data?**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't, unless it's a character encoding with a fixed octet-to-character ratio (which is unlikely for JSON because it'll be UTF-8 in most cases)
2. Well, as byte arrays :-)
3. You could try to skip to the first byte sequence that is valid according to the encoding used. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-4 should have the necessary details.